# Testing Grails 3 app with 'gradle test' uses wrong environment config

Tags: grails, gradle

I have a Grails 3 application that I'm trying to configure an embedded datastore for functional tests for. I have the configuration for the datastore specific to the 'test' environment.

When I run 'grails test-app', the app connects to the correct datastore and my functional tests pass.

When I try testing the application with 'gradle test', it tries to connect to the datastore for the development environment and fails.

I have tried specifying the Grails environment to use for the gradle test task by adding this to build.gradle:

```
test {
    String testEnvArg = '-Dgrails.env=test'

    if (jvmArgs) {
        jvmArgs.add(testEnvArg)
    } else {
        jvmArgs = [testEnvArg]
    }
}
```

But the behavior appears to be unchanged.

How can I make the gradle 'test' task use the correct Grails environment configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must specify environment:

```
gradle -PgrailsEnv=test test
```

Answer (score 1):

To boot run with production environment and gradle wrapper below worked:

./gradlew -Dgrails.env=production bootRun

And with requested test environment:

./gradlew -Dgrails.env=test bootRun

Comment: Confirmed with grails 3.1.14 and gradle 2.14.1